# Is there a more efficient way to update a JSON file?

Tags: php, json

I'm developing a browser-based game, and for the combat instances I need to be able track the player's hit points as well as the NPC's hit points. I'm thinking setting up a JSON file for each instance makes more sense then having a mySQL db get hammered with requests constantly. I've managed to create the JSON file, pull the contents, update the relevant vars, then overwrite the file, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to handling it than how I've set it up.

```php
$new_data = array(
    "id"=>"$id",
    "master_id"=>"$master_id",
    "leader"=>"$leader",
    "group"=>"$group",
    "ship_1"=>"$ship_1",
    "ship_2"=>"$ship_2",
    "ship_3"=>"$ship_3",
    "date_start"=>"$date_start",
    "date_end"=>"$date_end",
    "public_private"=>"$public_private",
    "passcode"=>"$passcode",
    "npc_1"=>"$npc_1",
    "npc_1_armor"=>"$npc_1_armor",
    "npc_1_shields"=>"$npc_1_shields",
    "npc_2"=>"$npc_2",
    "npc_2_armor"=>"$npc_2_armor",
    "npc_2_shields"=>"$npc_2_shields",
    "npc_3"=>"$npc_3",
    "npc_3_armor"=>"$npc_3_armor",
    "npc_3_shields"=>"$npc_3_shields",
    "npc_4"=>"$npc_4",
    "npc_4_armor"=>"$npc_4_armor",
    "npc_4_shields"=>"$npc_4_shields",
    "npc_5"=>"$npc_5",
    "npc_5_armor"=>"$npc_5_armor",
    "npc_5_shields"=>"$npc_5_shields",
    "ship_turn"=>"$ship_turn",
    "status"=>"$status");

$new_data = json_encode($new_data);
$file = "$id.json";
file_put_contents($file, $new_data);
```

It works, but I'm wondering if there is a way to update a single array item w/o having to pull ALL the data out, assign it to vars, and re-write the file. in this example, I'm only changing one var (ship_turn)

Comment: *"I'm thinking setting up a JSON file for each instance makes more sense then having a mySQL db get hammered with requests constantly."* ... why?

Comment: Database servers are **designed** to be hammered with requests and come with all sorts of useful features to prevent race conditions when multiple things are being updated at the same time.

Comment: This is the purpose of databases, being hammered by requests

Comment: @CD001 – Each user will be querying the DB every few seconds to see if it's their turn, and to update hit points. I was concerned that that if I have 1000 players reading/writing the DB every few seconds, that might cause issues. No?

Comment: @JonWenzel - it'll cause far fewer issues than attempting to do something similar using a text (json) file ;)

Comment: I guess my main reason for using a file over a db was each file would only be accessed by at most 3 people since each instance would have it's own file. The database would be used by every instance at once––I'm trying to set this up well in the event the game really takes off and has a ton of users.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking setting up a JSON file for each instance makes more sense then having a mySQL db get hammered with requests constantly.

MySQL is optimized for this task.

If you use files (like JSON) as database replacement, then you have to deal with "race conditions", because file access is not optimized for concurrent read / write access (by default).

If you're in a high-concurrency environment you should avoid using the filesystem as "database". Multiple operations on the file system are very hard to make atomic in PHP.

See [flock](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) for more details.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I appreciate the response. That is super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the game. For a turn based game or any non real-time game a `MySQL` approach should be ok. After all, databases are designed to get hammered heavily :-) For realtime games I would go for `WebSocket` and `NodeJS` as the backend. The server would keep a runtime state of the game, reacting appropriately to the client requests and dealing with race conditions (as you would do on a stand alone multiplayer server)

Comment: Cool, thanks. It's turn-based, but I guess I'm worried about querying the DB every 1 second for updates if there are many users. WebSockets seem intriguing, but that's a little beyond my coding abilities, sadly.